# Word for person who is boastful about knowing something was going to happen

Tags: single-word-requests

It seems like there is a gap in the English language here. The closest I can think of is a combination of "hipster" and "braggart".  Let's call it a "bragster" for the purpose of this question. I notice this behaviour is becoming increasingly common in a world of instant, but voluminous information.  Often the bragster's claim on prior knowledge can be called into question. A couple of examples:

A band becomes famous after a few false starts, a person who likes them because of their latest track or similar says to the bragster "Wow, have you heard of BandX? They are awesome!", where the bragster would respond with "BandX! I have been listening to them for a long time, their early stuff was much better, finally people recognise them". "Oh really, what is their early work like?". Bragster: "Better! (but I can't think of why right now)".

A financial crisis occurs.  The Bragster claims "I knew that would happen, it's because of situationY. I have been saying it was going to happen for years". "Oh really? I never heard you say anything?". Bragster: "Oh, I didn't think you were interested so never said anything".

I guess "braggart" fits, but in a world where the internet exists, this has become much more common to claim to have prior knowledge of current or future events.  This could also work as an adjective describing a behaviour as "bragstering" (which obviously is terrible, but you get the idea).

Comment: I think "know-it-all" is possibly closer than braggart, not sure, but in any case it isn't specific to this particular claim.

Comment: '...gap in the English language...'? Seriously? English is one heck of a pack-rat language. Try the German loan word *Wisenheimer* or its countless synonyms.

Comment: Wisenheimer works, let's adopt it!

Comment: Funny how nobody ever shows up here asking for our help in saying something ***nice*** about somebody else. Instead it's always about saying horrible things about something we disapprove of, even though this has never required fancy words to sting the worst.